# elastic search select only distinct with max field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that contain a version number:

```
{
  "original_id" : "1234",
  "version" : 1
}


{
  "original_id" : "1234",
  "version" : 2
}


{
  "original_id" : "4567",
  "version" : 1
}
```

I need to select only documents with distinct id's and max version number.

final result from this should be:

```
[
    {
        "original_id": 1234,
        "version" : 2
    },
    {
        "original_id" : 4567,
        "version" : 1
    }
]
```

I am completely confused by the documentation -- should I be using aggs? I did, but I still get all of them. I want just the top version

in SQL:

> select distinct(original_id) as id, max(version) as version from docs grouping by id;

Here is my current query:

```
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 25,
    "sort": [{
        "version": {
            "order": "desc",
            "mode": "max"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {"original_id": "95936d0b-0de4-44ad-81d3-b95d3200c27f"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "start" : {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you should be using aggregations. . .following is the query for your requirement.
`

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "original_id",
        "size": 0
      },"aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "max": {
            "field": "version"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`